# GWT RequestFactory: Is it possible to send Fake entity from client to server?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I'm using GWT 2.5rc2 request factory with GAE1.7, the server side use entity locator to load entity from datastore.

"Fake" entities means entities that are never stored in datastore, only used for transferring entity objects from server to client and vice versa.

Now i have a fake entity sent from server to client side is OK, but from client side to server side the locator will throw exception because it can not find the ID, if i set a random ID for fake entity, it will give exception: `The requested entity is not available on the server`

Any ideas on how to solve this problem or any workarounds?

Comment: Are you looking for `ValueProxy`?

Comment: No, because the real entity will be saved in datastore, but some of them are not suitable for saving in datastore, i just use them for transferring entity from client to server and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a container `ValueProxy` and embed `EntityProxy` objects.
Something like this:

```
@ProxyFor(AccountPage.class)
public interface AccountPageProxy extends ValueProxy  {
    public List<AccountProxy> getAccounts();
    int getNumber();
    long getTotalElements();
    int getTotalPages();
}

@ProxyFor(...)
public interface AccountProxy extends EntityProxy {

}
```

For example I use this approach to transfer a Page (start, end) of a list of `EntityProxy` to the client (see above example).